# Error building sample opencv application in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012, opencl

I am trying to build this sample opencv application with visual studio 2012:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/ocl/surf_matcher.cpp

To do this, I download and install opencv 2.4.6 and installed it on my system.

Configured visual studio 2012 to use it (set include path, library path and libraries)

I checked and I added all libraries in opencv\build\x86\vc11\staticlib to my application (I take care that debug libraries were added to debug build and release libraries to release build).

I am compiling the code, I am getting several link error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::ocl::SURF_OCL::SURF_OCL(double,int,int,bool,float,bool)" (??0SURF_OCL@ocl@cv@@QAE@NHH_NM0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall `anonymous namespace'::SURFDetector<class cv::ocl::SURF_OCL>::SURFDetector<class cv::ocl::SURF_OCL>(double)" (??0?$SURFDetector@VSURF_OCL@ocl@cv@@@?A0x1f01e08d@@QAE@N@Z) 

Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _clReleaseMemObject@4 ConsoleApplication1\opencv_ocl246d.lib(arithm.obj)
```

There are several of them and all of them seems related to ocl library.

Which other library should I add for OCL to work?

### Note:

When I tried to compile, I got the following error:

```
'getDeviceInfo' : is not a member of 'cv::ocl::Context'
```

on this code:

```
if(!useCPU)
{
    std::cout
            << "Device name:"
            << cv::ocl::Context::getContext()->getDeviceInfo().deviceName
            << std::endl;
}
```

This error seems relates to different ocl.hpp which is around. I used the github version (See answers for detail) and after changing the header that it needs, compile error solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are several versions of OpenCV. In one of them `cv::ocl::Context` does not have `getDeviceInfo` method.
http://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.6.1/classcv_1_1ocl_1_1Context.html

Second: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ocl/include/opencv2/ocl.hpp has it. I think you should use github's version.

**UPD:**

I think you need to build github version of the library to solve the first link error. You have missed https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/nonfree/src/surf.ocl.cpp . Also you must to install OpenCL SDK (Intel, AMD or CUDA depending on you graphics card) to solve the other one.

NVidia: https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl

AMD (both CPU and GPU): http://developer.amd.com/resources/heterogeneous-computing/opencl-zone/

Intel (both CPU and GPU): http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk

Comment: Thanks. That solved the compile error, but not link error. How can I fix the link error?

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. But if I use on of them, then my application doesn't work on another platform and hence why should I use OpenCL? is not the main aim of using opencl is that my application would work on all platfomrs that support opencl?

Comment: OpenCL designed to be cross-platform: http://www.khronos.org/opencl/ . So, you can install all of SDKs and then just select the version of SDK you are going to use. And you should use this standard because the program you are trying to compile use it :)

Comment: Does it means that I can not have one exe file that runs on all platform?

Comment: According to http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6299-OpenCL-ICD-infrastructure-questions only exe - no, you cannot. AFAIK, NVidia provides OpenCL.DLL, that is needed by your app, with the driver. I don't know a lot about ATI and Intel  drivers, but I needed to install the SDK to enable OpenCL. Hence, you should provide OpenCL.DLL with your exe just to be sure.

Comment: In addition, yes, if you provides OpenCL.DLL, the program will be run on all OpenCL-enabled devices, I think.